# Edit Access To Case Comments

Tags: case, admin

I Need a specific Profile users to have access to Edit Case Comments.
I tried 'Edit Case Comments' permission... But it is Saying "Can't save permission set Agency User, which is assigned to a user with user license Salesforce Platform. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Edit Case Comments
"
Could Anyone please Solve this..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, users, to which this permission set could be assigned should be `Salesforce`, not `Salesforce Platform` licence.

`Edit Case Comments` requires `Edit Case` permission. Which is not available for the `Salesforce Platform` license. Check [documentation about licence types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_available.htm&type=5)

> Designed for users who need access to custom apps but not to standard
> CRM functionality.

Comment: Thanks For Your Info.. And Is There Any Alternative Ways to Achieve it rather than using this 'Edit Case Comments' Permission...

Comment: @HaribhanuprasadNandarapu unfortunately, I don't think so

Comment: Ohh. Thank You sir.